# MYSQL query to get first 2 duplicates of each kind

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm having some problems with a query. In a table called tests I have lets say 4 columns, id, code, value, time. the values in code can (and are) duplicate, some times triplicated. so far i can query the database to get all the results that are duplicated. the problem is that i want to get only the first 2 rows from those duplicated rows. so if i have rows like:

```
1, dw9e87, 12, 2016-08-31 12:00:00;
2, dw9587, 3, 2016-08-31 10:30:00;
3, dw9587, 22, 2016-08-31 09:30:00;
4, qq5368, 10, 2016-08-31 09:35:00;
5, qq5368, 35, 2016-08-31 10:10:00;
```

the result should show:

```
1, dw9e87, 12, 2016-08-31 12:00:00;
2, dw9587, 3, 2016-08-31 10:30:00;
4, qq5368, 10, 2016-08-31 09:35:00;
5, qq5368, 35, 2016-08-31 10:10:00;
```

since in the case of the first code, the id 1 and 2 are newer. is it possible to do this in a query? thanks!

Comment: you want to get all duplicate records ?

Comment: Sorry,  the question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. What do you mean "get the first 2 rows from those duplicate rows"?

Comment: ok, maybe i didn't give much information... sorry. imagine that the table has a lot of records, this is just an example. now  the idea is to get back only the duplicates in the column "code" and if there is a triplication, get only the first 2. does it make more sense now? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the first two duplicated records, then variables come to mind:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = code, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := code, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := '') params
      order by code, time desc
     ) t
where rn <= 2;
```

Actually, that doesn't quite work, because it returns singletons as well.  So:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = code, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := code, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := '') params
      where code in (select code from t group by code having count(*) >= 2)
      order by code, time desc
     ) t
where rn <= 2 ;
```